# how can i connect my google sql postgres to my django application?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, google-cloud-sql

I have create my google postgres instance on cloud sql service, and i couldn't connect it with my django application,

[image]

in the link below they give sqlalchemy configuration, but nothing about the database host

```
[cloud.google](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy#debianubuntu )
```

This is
my database credentials

```
# GCP DATABASE CREDENTIALS
DB_NAME=db_name 
DB_HOST= ***
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=db_user 
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Not sure about the DB_HOST, i tried the public ip address of my db and it not working i got this error

[image]

This is my Django settings :

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT")  # default postgres port
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to either:

1. Run the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy locally next to your Django app
2. Allowlist your machine's IP address using Authorized Networks

There's more about the Proxy here:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy and
- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy